# How to catch a thrown exception in the calling class

Tags: java, jsf

I got a method that throw an exception if I try to insert an existing object in DB.

```
 public void addInDB() throws Exception {
    if (isInBase()){
          throw new Exception ("[ReqFamily->addInDB] requirment already in base");
    }
    int idParent = m_parent.getIdBdd();

    idBdd = pSQLRequirement.add(name, description, 0, idParent,   
    ReqPlugin.getProjectRef().getIdBdd(), 100);
}
```

So when the exception is thrown I wanna catch it and display an error messsage in my managed bean.

PS: In my managed bean I just call the method :

```
void addReq(Requirement req){
    try {
        ReqFamily pReqParent = (ReqFamily) selectedNode.getData();
        req.setParent(pReqParent);
        req.addInDB();//here i want to catch it 


        DefaultTreeNode newReqNode = new DefaultTreeNode(req,selectedNode);
        if (pReqParent!=null){
            pReqParent.addRequirement(req);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex){

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean catch exception there and log it and continue with further processing?

Comment: i meant preventing throwing the exception and instead displaying an error message to the user : this object already  exists in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its bad practice to catch or throw `Exception`. If any code you use throws a checked exception then just catch that specific exception, and try to minimize the size of your `try-catch` blocks.

```
class MyException extends Exception {
    ...

public void addInDB() throws MyException {
    if (isInBase()){
        throw new MyException ("[ReqFamily->addInDB] requirment already in base");
    }
    ...

void addReq(Requirement req){
    ReqFamily pReqParent = (ReqFamily) selectedNode.getData();
    req.setParent(pReqParent);

    try {
        req.addInDB();
    } catch (MyException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    DefaultTreeNode newReqNode = new DefaultTreeNode(req,selectedNode);
    if (pReqParent!=null){
        pReqParent.addRequirement(req);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        try {
            req.addInDB();//here i want to catch it 
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
void addReq(Requirement req){
    try {
        ReqFamily pReqParent = (ReqFamily) selectedNode.getData();
        req.setParent(pReqParent);
        req.addInDB();//here i want to catch it 


        DefaultTreeNode newReqNode = new DefaultTreeNode(req,selectedNode);
        if (pReqParent!=null){
            pReqParent.addRequirement(req);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

If you wanna capture all of stacktrace to be show in display, you can use this:

```
catch (Exception ex) {

   String
   ls_exception = "";

   for (StackTraceElement lo_stack : ex.getStackTrace()) {

      ls_exception += "\t"+lo_stack.toString()+"\r\n";

   }

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ls_exception);
}
```